# Incorporate small swift project into another swift project

Tags: swift

I have a swift project in Xcode that I am working on. I'll call it the primary project. I have most of it working. I was having trouble with date pickers, date ranges and date math so I started another project called StarEndDate with just one table view controller so I could tinker without messing up the primary project that is working. I finally have everything working the I want it in  the StartEndDate project and now want to implement what I learned in the primary project. Do I just copy and paste chunks of code between the 2 projects or is there another less burdensome way to incorporate the small swift project into the primary project? I will never use any of the code again so I wanted to keep it simple. I can't seem to phrase what I want to do in searches well enough to get any results that would help so I would also appreciate help on how to describe what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would probably be just adding these files from the original project into your new project.

So, if you right click (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click) in the project navigator, you get this menu:

[image]

Alternatively, from the top bar, you can open the "File" menu:

[image]

Either way, you want to select:

> "Add Files to "YourProjectName"...

Or, you can use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Anyway, this will open up a window from which you can navigate to and select the files you want to add to your project.  For this scenario, I'd recommend making sure you have "Copy items if needed" checked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I see the .swift file to add but what about all the storyboard stuff? And connections?

Comment: Ok - that was really weird. I copy and pasted the code and a little mini story board came along with it. All the connections were still there! This stuff is magic! But it bugged me that I could not find the mini storyboard listed anywhere. But I had a reference to a class that existed in my small project that was a different name in the primary project. Fixed that and I seem to be back in business! When weird things happen I am never sure if it is my lack of understanding or magic or flakiness of Swift that will rear its ugly head later. Thank you for your response with screen shots and all!